# PayPal Address_Override not working

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm testing a PayPal integration on the sandbox using cmd=_express-checkout
(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&=token=..)

The store I'm working on calcs shipping costs from delivery address before initialising the PayPal transaction, so we need to display the shipping address as entered on our client's site and not the default address held by PayPal for the buyer.

I've tried sending address_override=1 along with the address parameters specified here (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) but the [Ship To] displayed is still that of the test account default address.

```
address_override=1
useraction=commit
token=XXXX
address1=XXXX
city=XXXX
state=CA
country=US
zip=XXXXX
first_name=XXX
last_name=XXX
```

Am I missing something obvious or should I be doing it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have set NOSHIPPING=0.
Please change your request and set NOSHIPPING=2

**NOSHIPPING**
Determines whether PayPal displays shipping address fields on the PayPal pages. For digital goods, this field is required, and you must set it to 1. Value is:

0 — PayPal displays the shipping address on the PayPal pages.
1 — PayPal does not display shipping address fields and removes shipping information from the transaction.
2 — If you do not pass the shipping address, PayPal obtains it from the buyer's account profile.

Another one thing is for Express checkout integration you need to refer the documentation in here: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

The link that you have provided earlier is for paypal payment standard integration.

Comment: It's worth noting that our payment merchant (RealEx) generates the initial PayPal request and we don't see all the parameters passed or the request format. 

RealEx returns the token to us which we pass in a 2nd client-side browser request to PayPal for authorisation.

Given this two stage approach, at which point can/should the address be overridden / hidden? I wonder if it is simply too late to change the address on the second authorisation request?

Answer (score 0):

This will requires us to pull the log.

Kindly create an MTS ticket at our Technical Portal (https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) and provide the EC token for further checking.

Comment: I raised a ticket 29th Match on paypal-techsupport, not sure if it was in the right place but it doesn't have an answer yet (Incident: 170329-000101)